# Is there a way(s) to keep developer credentials in Magento project hidden?

Tags: magento-2.1, credentials

I'd like to store developer credentials (like name, email or something like that) inside Magento site, unlike putting `(c) developer` in footer , but somewhat hidden somewhere. only person who put that/developer can know there is that information stored. Also it should be able to be displayed when needed to.

Is there any way/ways someone can do this?

Comment: credentials to what?

Comment: @Marius like developer's name and email or something like that